# Python inheritance example

Tags: python, inheritance

Python newbie question.

I run the following example:

```
class Polygon:
  def __init__(polygonType):
    print('Polygon is a ', polygonType)

class Triangle(Polygon):
  def __init__(self):
    Polygon.__init__('triangle')

print(issubclass(Triangle, Polygon))
print(issubclass(Triangle, list))
print(issubclass(Triangle, (list, Polygon)))
print(issubclass(Polygon, (list, Polygon)))
```

This is the output:

```
True
False
True
True
```

Why do the two last `print` statements yield `true`? Does it have any practical meaning or only theoretical?

Comment: *"[`issubclass(class, classinfo)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) – Return true if `class` is a subclass (direct, indirect or virtual) of `classinfo`. A class is considered a subclass of itself. `classinfo` may be a tuple of class objects, in which case every entry in `classinfo` will be checked."* – I think that's pretty clear. What don't you understand about this behaviour and/or explanation?

Comment: Also note that it should be `def __init__(self, polygonType)`, and `super().__init__('triangle')`…

Comment: Might be confusing that it returns `True` the class is a subclass of **At least one** of the classes in the tuple.

Comment: issubclass(Triangle, (list, Polygon)) - In which situations might this be necessary for practice?

Comment: @purpletentacle that one is actually explicitly written in the docs (see deceze's comment). It makes sense from a mathematical point of view (any set is a subset of itself since it contains all the elements of itself).

Comment: @user3139228 TBH I have never seen it used. Perhaps if you want to check against several classes inheriting from a single ancestor, but exclude another class inheriting from same ancestor. I still cannot think of a good use for that though.

Comment: *"If this is a subclass of A or B (or C or D), do something…"* – Seems like a pretty useful, typical situation to run into. Being able to pass a tuple saves you from having to write `if issubclass(a, b) or issubclass(a, c) or issubclass(a, d)…`.